# Ionic ion-select-option is not working when used a service as provided values directly in the template

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Strange thing have happend for me that I would like to share and may be some on knows why this happens.

So the template:

```
<ion-select>
  <ion-select-option
    *ngFor="let transportMode of transportService.getTransportModes()"
    [value]="transportMode.id"
  >
    {{ transportMode.name }}
  </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

in the `.ts` file the service is just injected:

```
  constructor(
    protected transportService: TransportService,
  ) {}
```

The service, just returns an array of id/name pair values. Like this:

```
  getTransportModes(): TransportMode[] {
    return [
      {
        id: TransportModeTypes.VAN,
        name: 'Van',
      },
      {
        id: TransportModeTypes.TRACTOR,
        name: 'Tractor',
      },
      {
        id: TransportModeTypes.TRAILER,
        name: 'Trailer',
      },
      {
        id: TransportModeTypes.SHIP,
        name: 'Ship',
      },
    ];
  }
```

```
export enum TransportModeTypes {
  VAN = 1,
  TRACTOR = 2,
  TRAILER = 3,
  SHIP = 4,
}
```

```
export interface TransportMode {
  id: TransportModeTypes;
  name: string;
}
```

This Ionic perfectly builds the select field, but when I click the dropdown to display it shows a popup with values and radio-buttons, and the radio buttons are not clickable, so I cannot choose a value. Which is very strange behavior.

If I change in the template and store the value in a separate property - then the select works good.

Working example:

template:

```
<ion-select>
  <ion-select-option
    *ngFor="let transportMode of transportModes"
    [value]="transportMode.id"
  >
    {{ transportMode.name }}
  </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

the `.ts` file:

```
  protected transportModes!: TransportMode[];

  constructor(
    private transportService: TransportService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.transportModes = this.transportService.getTransportModes();
  }
```

I cannot explain and guess, why this works, and the above variant is not working.
Any ideas?

I attach the version, just for more info:

```
 "@angular/core": "^15.2.7",
 "@ionic/angular": "7.0.3",
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to check if your select options actually become clickable after a while (and how fast).

However, it seems to me like an issue with calling methods under ngFor directive, as it will be checked/re-rendered on each check for change in the DOM. Even if the values on which `getTransportModes()` rely are not changed, the method will be executed on each check. Now, even if that is definitely a reason to reconsider the logic and possibly use a var which value will be set in the ts (as you mentioned in the situation that works ok), it's also important to know how often your DOM is checked for changes.

Are there some mouse events that are triggered too often? Some other method calls from the template? If your template is such that it triggers many methods on each DOM check, it might be clogging your flow.

Comment: Agreed on all that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there must be something else causing a problem for you here.

Here's a [barebones test](https://github.com/pecknigel/ionic-angular-ts-experimentation/tree/317690c176b1db234442933d2008ee6e18824b45) using the code that you provided. As you expect, It makes no difference whether the data is fetched from a service via ngOnInit and stored in a property or fetched directly from the component template.

See "Transport One" for fetching it from the component template.

See "Transport Two" for fetching it via ngOnInit and storing it in a property.